# Sort at various levels in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of tuples like these:

```
[('Pineapple', 1), ('Orange', 3), ('Banana', 1), ('Apple', 1), ('Cherry', 2)]
```

The sorted list should be:

```
[('Orange', 3), ('Cherry', 2), ('Apple', 1), ('Banana', 1), ('Pineapple', 1)]
```

So, here 1st the list should be sorted based on `tuple[1]` in descending order, then if the `tuple` values (`tuple[1]`) match like for`Apple`, `Banana` & `Pineapple` - list should be further sorted based on `tuple[0]` in ascending order.

I have tried the possible ways-

```
top_n.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(1, 0), reverse = True)
# Output: [(Orange, 3), (Cherry, 2), (Pineapple, 1), (Banana, 1), (Apple, 1)]
```

as `"reverse = True"`, Pineapple, then Banana,...

I finally had to come up with a solution:

```
top_n.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(0), reverse = False)
top_n.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
```

Is there any better way to get to the solution like my 1st approach. I am trying to explore more about Python, thus seeking such kind of solution.

Comment: Actually you could simply do: `top_n.sort(); top_n.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)`.  Because `reverse=False` is the default. Also using `itemgetter(0)` doesn't really make too much sense since sequences are already sorted by the first element first so you can simply avoid using `key`.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Yeah! True. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, Martijn Pieters solution is probably the best, but I was considering what you would do if you needed to do this for any number of parameters, and needed to do some ascending and some descending.

This approach creates a function to generate a sort index on the fly.  Calling getsortfunction with the list of tuples to sort and a list containing the indices and if they should be in reverse order (for example `(2,True)` means second index in reverse order), returns a function which creates the sort index for an object.  It is *pretty ugly*, but versatile.

```
def getsortfunction(values,indices):
    sorts = [sorted(list(set(x[indices[i][0]] for x in values)),reverse=indices[i][1]) for i in range(len(indices))]
    def sortfunction(y):
        return tuple(sorts[i].index(y[indices[i][0]]) for i in range(len(indices)))
    return sortfunction
```

Examples

```
a = [('Pineapple',1),('Orange',3),('Banana',1),('Apple',1),('Cherry',2)]
# sort a by index 1 first (in reverse order) and then by index 0 in non-reverse order
b = sorted(a,key=getsortfunction(a,[(1,True),(0,False)])) # gives desired list
```

With an additional criteria

```
c = [('Pineapple',1,'Hawaii'),('Orange',3,'Florida'),('Banana',1,'Hawaii'),('Apple',1,'Washington'),('Cherry',2,'Washington')]
# sort first by number (in reverse order) then by state, and finally by fruit
d = sorted(c,key=getsortfunction(c,[(1,True),(2,False),(0,False)]))

# sort c first by number (in reverse order), then by fruit, ignoring state
e = sorted(c,key=getsortfunction(c,[(1,True),(0,False)]))
```

The getsortfunction first builds a nested list of unique values in order and returns a function which maps each value to be sorted to a numeric tuple giving its indices in the sorted value list.

The biggest advantage of this is that you can determine the sort criteria at runtime (for instance from user requests).

Comment: That's the kind of solution I was trying, but I thought maybe I am overdoing it (new to Python) and stopped it. Though it's little ugly, I believe this is the effective solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

Have your key return a tuple of the numeric value *negated*, and then the string. By negating, your numbers will be sorted in descending order, while the strings are sorted in ascending order:

```
top_n.sort(key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0]))
```

Yes, this is a bit of a hack, but works anywhere you need to sort by two criteria in opposite directions, and one of those criteria is numeric.

Demo:

```
>>> top_n = [('Pineapple', 1), ('Orange', 3), ('Banana', 1), ('Apple', 1), ('Cherry', 2)]
>>> sorted(top_n, key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0]))
[('Orange', 3), ('Cherry', 2), ('Apple', 1), ('Banana', 1), ('Pineapple', 1)]
```

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that the negation only works for integers. I cannot propose anything better, my solution was the same.

Comment: What if both tuples arguments were string?

Comment: @Arman: further hacking: convert the string to a sequence of negated integers (`[-chr(c) for c in string]`).

Comment: @Arman: or do what the OP did; sort first by the minor criterion in one direction, then sort *again* on the major criteria.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wonderful , Thanks!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks a lot! I don't consider it as a hack, very clever! Moreover it brought some clarity.